# Undefined index and Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

In this below code when i update without checking any value it displays all the values from db.And error  Undefined variable: records and  Invalid argument supplied for foreach() at 113 and 119
    Undefined variable: row in line 123
    Trying to get property of non-object in 123in student_detail_view.

Please any one help me.

Controller student_site:

```
    function index()
    {   
        $data = array();
        if($query = $this->student_model->get_exam_data())
        {
            $data['exam_data'] = $query;
        }
        $this->load->view('student_view', $data);
    }

    function studentupdate()
    {   
        $data = array();
        $exam_name = $this->input->post('exam_name');
        $course_name = $this->input->post('course_name');
        if($query = $this->student_model->get_exam_data())
        {
            $data['exam_data'] = $query;
        }
        if($query = $this->student_model->get_records($exam_name))
        {
            $data['records'] = $query;
        }
                if($query = $this->student_model->get_course_code_records($exam_name))
        {
            $data['course_records'] = $query;
        }
        if($query = $this->student_model->get_all_coursesubject_records())
        {
            $data['all_coursesubject_records'] = $query;
        }
        $this->load->view('student_detail_view', $data);
    }

    function studentcreate()
    {   
        $data = array();
        $exam_name = $this->input->post('exam_name');
        $data['exam_name'] = $exam_name;
        /*if($query = $this->student_model->get_exam_data())
        {
            $data['exam_data'] = $query;
        }*/
        if($query = $this->student_model->get_course_code_records($exam_name))  //get unique records of coursecode from the coursesubject table
        {
            $data['course_records'] = $query;
        }

        /*if($query = $this->student_model->get_subject_code_records($exam_name)) //write seperate function to get the the subject codes frm the coursesubject table based on the selected course code.
        {
            $data['subject_records'] = $query;
        }   */
        $this->load->view('student_update', $data);
    }   


    function subject_records()
    {   
        $data = array();
        $exam_name = $this->input->post('exam_name');
        $course_name = $this->input->post('course_name');
        if($query = $this->student_model->get_subject_records($exam_name,$course_name))
        {
            $data['subject_records'] = $query;
        }
        $this->load->view('subject_view', $data);
    }


    function create_student()
    {
    /*$data = $this->input->post();
    print_r($data);
    var_dump($this->input->post());
    $data=$this->input->post();*/
    $j=1; 
    $createstudent = $this->input->post('createstudent');

            if( $this->input->post('createstudent') != false ){
            foreach($createstudent as $row_id)
            {
                $this->form_validation->set_rules("register_number_" . $row_id, "Register No", "required|min_length[2]");
                //$this->form_validation->set_rules("name_". $row_id,"`Name`","required|xss_clean|min_length[1]");

                }
            }

            if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE){

                $data["message"]="";


                $this->load->view("student_detail_view",$data);
                //$this->load->view("master_data/view_master_data_footer");

            }

    while($j<=$this->uri->segment(3))

   {

        $data = array(
        'exam_name' => $this->input->post('exam_name'),
        'register_number' => $this->input->post('register_number_'.$j),
        'name' => $this->input->post('name_'.$j),
        'course_code' => $this->input->post('course_name_id'.$j),
        'subject_code' => $this->input->post('subject_name'),

        );
        // $exam_name   = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["exam_name_id".$j]);//
          $register_number=$this->input->post('register_number_'.$j);
            if ($register_number != "")
                {       
                $this->student_model->add_record($data);
                }

        $j++;
    }
    redirect('student_site', 'refresh');


    }

    function delete()
    {
    $this->student_model->delete_row();
     redirect('student_site', 'refresh');
    }

    function manage_student()
    {
        $data['title']="Manage Student";
            //query model to get data results for form
            $data=array();
            if($query=$this->student_model->get_student_records()){
            $data['records']=$query;
            }
            $editstudent = $this->input->post('editstudent');
            if( $this->input->post('editstudent') != false ){
            foreach($editstudent as $row_id)
            {
                $this->form_validation->set_rules("register_number_" . $row_id, "register_number", "required|min_length[2]");


            }
            }
            if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE){
            $data["message"]="";

                //$this->load->view("master_data/view_master_data_header",$data);
                //$this->load->view("master_data/view_master_data_nav");
                $this->load->view("student_detail_view",$data);
                //$this->load->view("master_data/view_master_data_footer");

            } else {
                // single update - working
                if( $this->input->post('editstudent') != false )
                {
                    foreach ($editstudent as $row_id)
                    {
                        $data = array( 
                        'register_number' => $this->input->post('register_number_'.$row_id),
                        'name' => $this->input->post('name_'.$row_id),
                        'course_code' => $this->input->post('course_code_id'.$row_id),
                        'subject_code' => $this->input->post('subject_code_id'.$row_id),

                        );

                        $this->student_model->update_student_records( $row_id, $data );

                    }
                    $this->session->set_flashdata('dbaction', 'Selected Records have been updated successfully');
                    redirect('student_site', 'refresh');

                    }

            }
    }
    $data = array(
'exam_name' => $this->input->post('exam_name_id'),
'register_number' => $this->input->post('register_number'),
'name' => $this->input->post('name'),
'subject_code' => $this->input->post('subject_code'),
'course_code' => $this->input->post('course_code'),
);
$exam_name = $this->input->post('exam_name');
$register_number = $this->input->post('register_number');
$name = $this->input->post('name');
$course_code = $this->input->post('course_code');
$subject_code = $this->input->post('subject_code');
$this->student_model->update_student_record($exam_name,$register_number,$name,$course_code,$subject_code,$data);
$data = array();
$query = $this->student_model->get_records($exam_name);
echo "<pre>";
print_r($query);
exit;
if($query)
{
    $data['records'] = $query;
}
$this->load->view('student_detail_view', $data);
    function crud()
    {       
    }
    function deleting()
    {       
    }
```

model:student_model

```
function get_records($exam_name)
{
    $this->db->where('exam_name',$exam_name);
    $query = $this->db->get('student_table');
    return $query->result();

}
function get_exam_data()
{
    $this->db->distinct();
    $this->db->select("CONCAT(exam_name, ' ', month,' ',year) AS fullexamname", FALSE);//this will concat the value
    $query = $this->db->get('exam_table');
    return $query->result();
}
function get_course_records($exam_name)
{
    //echo "exam_name".$exam_name;
    $this->db->select('exam_name,course_code');
    $this->db->where('exam_name',$exam_name);
    $query = $this->db->get('student_table');
    return $query->result();

}
function get_subject_records($exam_name,$course_name)
{
    //echo "exam_name inside get_subject_records".$exam_name;
    $this->db->select('subject_code');
    //$this->db->where('exam_name',$exam_name);
    $this->db->where('course_code',$course_name);
    $query = $this->db->get('coursesubject');
    return $query->result();

}

function get_all_coursesubject_records()
{
    //echo "exam_name inside get_subject_records".$exam_name;
    $this->db->select('course_code');
    $this->db->select('subject_code');
    $query = $this->db->get('coursesubject');
    return $query->result();

}   
function get_course_code_records($course_name)
{
    $query = $this->db->get('coursesubject');
    return $query->result();

}
function get_subject_code_records()
{
    $this->db->distinct();
    $this->db->select('subject_code');

    $query = $this->db->get('coursesubject');
    return $query->result();

}
function update_student_record($exam_name,$register_number,$name,$course_code, $subject_code,$data)
    {
        echo "exam_name".$exam_name;
        echo "register_number".$register_number;
        echo "name".$name;
        $this->db->where('exam_name',$exam_name);
        $this->db->where('register_number',$register_number);
        //$this->db->where('name',$name);
        //$this->db->where('course_code',$course_code);
        //$this->db->where('subject_code',$subject_code);
        $this->db->update('student_table',$data);  
    }
```

view :student_detail_view

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url();?>js/jquery.dataTables.js" ></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url();?>js/jquery.dataTables.min.js" ></script>
<section id="tables">
<script>
 jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  oTable = jQuery('#studenttable').dataTable({
   "bJQueryUI": true,
   "sPaginationType": "full_numbers"

  });
   }); 
  </script> 
  <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
 function get_studentdetails() {

    var exam_name = jQuery('#exam_name_id').val();
    //alert("exam_name"+exam_name);
    jQuery.ajax({
        data: {
            exam_name: exam_name,
        },
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'student_site/studentupdate',          
        success: function(data){
        //alert("inside change");
            console.log(data);
            jQuery('#details').html(data);
            jquery('#deleting').html(data);
        }
    });
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery.ajax({
        data: {
            exam_name: exam_name,
        },
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'student_site/studentcreate',
        success: function(data){
        //alert("inside change");
            console.log(data);
            jQuery('#crud').html(data);
            jquery('#deleting').html(data);
        }
    }); 
    });
}     

function CheckBoxVerification(From)
{
alert('hai');
    alert('hai:' $("table input[type=checkbox]:checked").length);
    if(From == "Insert")
    {
        if(!!$('#rowInsert input:checked').length == false)
        {
            alert('please select at least one check box to Create ...!');
        }
    }

    if(From == "Update")
    {
        if(!!$('#rowUpdate input:checked').length == false)
        {
            alert('please select at least one check box to Update ...!');
        }
    }
}
  function get_subjectdetails() {
    //var index = jQuery('#index').val();

    var course_name = jQuery('#course_name_id').val();
    //alert("course_name"+course_name);
    //var exam_name = jQuery('#course_name_id>option:selected').text();
    var exam_name = jQuery('#exam_name_id').val();
    var ssubject_code = jQuery('#ssubject_code_id').val();
    //var partsArray = exam_name.split('.');
    //alert("ssubject_code"+ssubject_code);
    //alert("course_name"+course_name);
    //alert("exam_name"+exam_name);
    jQuery.ajax({
        data: 'exam_name='+exam_name+'&course_name=' + course_name,
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'student_site/subject_records',
        success: function(data){
        //alert("inside change");
            console.log(data);
            //alert ("data"+data);
            //for(var j = course_name; j < ssubject_code; j++)
        //{
            jQuery('#ssubject_code').empty().append(data);
        //}
        }

    });
} 

</script>

<?php 
    $attributes=array(
        'name'=>'updatecustomer',
        'id'=>'updatecustomer'
        );
    echo form_open('student_site/manage_student',$attributes);
?>
<div id="validation_failed">
    <?php
        echo validation_errors();
    ?>
    <?php $data = array();
        foreach ($records as $row)
        {
            $data[$row->course_code] = $row->course_code; 
        } 

        $subject_data = array();
        foreach ($records as $row)
        {
            $subject_data[$row->subject_code] = $row->subject_code; 
        }  
        var_dump($row->course_code );

     ?>
     <div id="Processy">
<table class="display table table-bordered table-striped" id='studenttable'>
<thead>
<tr font style='font-size:13px'>
<th>&nbsp;</th>
<th>&nbsp;</th>
<th>Register Number</th>
<th>Name </th>
<th>Course Code</th>
<th>Subject Code</th>
</tr></thead>
<?php if(isset($records)) : foreach($records as $row) : ?>
<tr >
<td>
<?php echo anchor('student_site/delete/'.$row->id, 'Delete',array('onClick'=>"return confirm('Are you sure want to delete..?')")); ?>
</td>
<td id="rowUpdate">
<input type=checkbox name="editstudent[]" id="editstudent[]" value="<?php echo $row->id ?>">
</td>
<td ><input class="inputmedium span2" type="text" name="register_number_<?php echo $row->id ?>" id="register_number_<?php echo $row->id ?>" value="<?php echo $row->register_number; ?>" ></td>
<td ><input class="inputmedium span2" type="text" name="name_<?php echo $row->id ?>" id="name_<?php echo $row->id ?>" value="<?php echo $row->name; ?>" ></td>

<td >
<?php 

        $js = 'class="dropdown_class" id="course_code_id'.$row->id.'" onChange="get_subjectdetails()" '; 
        $js_name = 'course_code_id'.$row->id;
        echo form_dropdown($js_name, $data, $row->course_code, $js);
?>
</td>
<td>    
<?php 

        $js = 'class="dropdown_class" id="subject_code_id'.$row->id.'"'; 
        $js_name = 'subject_code_id'.$row->id;
        echo form_dropdown($js_name, $subject_data, $row->subject_code, $js);

?>
<div id="ssubject_code" ></div>
<input type="hidden" name="ssubject_code" id="ssubject_code" value="ssubject_code"/>
</td>

</tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</table>
</div>
<center>
<br /><input type="submit" class="btn-success btn" value="Update Student"></center>

<?php else : ?>
<h2>No records were returned.</h2>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: it means your array element records is not set.....try the query on phpMyadmin..

Comment: Which lines are 113, 119 and 123 ?

Comment: it is in view : student_detail_view @ C. Malet

Comment: I have posted get_records @ Sonali

Comment: posted answer for debug just check

Comment: It shows null because there is no value if there are many values it shows only last value .but when i click update without checking the checkbox it displays all the values @sonali

Comment: In your view file search for $data = array(); and remove this line...remove the echo "<pre>"; print_r($query); exit; from controller

Answer (score 0):

you should check if $record is set and then use foreach.
Try something like:

```
if(isset($records)){
   foreach($records as $row){
      //do things here
   }
}
```

Comment: it shows error Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '{' in C:\wamp\www\Ci_Seatapp22-Ds\application\views\student_detail_view.php on line 113

Comment: @moses Added a missing parenthesis.

Answer (score 0):

Try echo on the records you get from the query as follows:

```
function update()
{

    $data = array(
    'exam_name' => $this->input->post('exam_name_id'),
    'register_number' => $this->input->post('register_number'),
    'name' => $this->input->post('name'),
    'subject_code' => $this->input->post('subject_code'),
    'course_code' => $this->input->post('course_code'),
    );
    $exam_name = $this->input->post('exam_name');
    $register_number = $this->input->post('register_number');
    $name = $this->input->post('name');
    $course_code = $this->input->post('course_code');
    $subject_code = $this->input->post('subject_code');
    $this->student_model->update_student_record($exam_name,$register_number,$name,$course_code,$subject_code,$data);
    $data = array();
    $query = $this->student_model->get_records($exam_name);
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($query);
    exit;
    if($query)
    {
        $data['records'] = $query;
    }
    $this->load->view('student_detail_view', $data);
}
```

Comment: Where to place this code: $this->student_model->get_records($exam_name) @Sonali

Comment: nope, just copy paste the controller code i have pasted above....instead of your controller I have added echo "<pre>";
    print_r($query);
    exit; in my controller

Comment: it shows this error  Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ECHO in student_site